# Open space office for team work?

Tags: office-layout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there evidence to suggest that certain office layouts are better than others for productivity?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/235/is-there-evidence-to-suggest-that-certain-office-layouts-are-better-than-others)

An argument I often hear to justify open space office layout is that, being open, it contributes to team work and more collaboration between people.

Does it really contributes to team work, compared to private offices? Is there hard data that might support this?

Comment: This question is about collaboration and the duplicated question is about productivity. Exact duplicate?

Comment: Please feel free to edit your question so that the differences are clearly delineated, and how answers to your question would be different than the answers to the other. The community would then vote to reopen or not based on those edits.

Comment: I can't because I don't know why the question has been closed. The two questions are related but they are not about the same subject.

Comment: The question has been closed because the community feels that they are the same.  Please feel free to discuss this in Meta or Chat.